# Sensitivity Analysis of ANN models

Tags: neural-networks, validation, sensitivity-analysis

I am a beginner in neural networks. I have split my data into training, validation and testing (out-of-sample hold-out set) and trained several models using MLP in Dell Statistica. I want to test sensitivity of the selected models implemented. Which dataset should i use?

Comment: Good that you're thinking about sensitivity analysis, I don't see that too often in applied work.

Answer (score 1):

Use whichever data set you used to estimate your prediction accuracy. So if you estimate accuracy on your test set, run sensitivity analysis on your test set. When you present your final results from the validation set, you should run a sensitivity analysis on the validation set.